# ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gtk, opencv

How should I solve this error in Ubuntu16.04?

```
    import cv2
  File "/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: At first fix your APT errors, then install `libglib2.0-0` package.

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```

Then, run your command again.  If that doesn't do the trick, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386
```

I'm on a 64-bit computer, but the tool I'm using uses 32-bit.

Comment: You might want to use ... apt-get ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to install

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Janin answer worked for me however I needed to first run `apt-get update -y`. I assume this is because I was running in a container with perhaps a different version of Ubuntu.

Full solution -

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```